# How can I specify a cacerts file in gradle jibDockerBuild?

Tags: docker, gradle, jib, cacerts

I have a spring boot app from which I am making an https call to another application whose certificate I need to add to my cacerts in order for the connection to succeed. Otherwise, it throws the following Exception

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I verified that this works properly by using a non-dockerized deployment. So, I know what the issue is and the remedy.

How can I specify a cacerts file for the jibDocker Image I create from gradle?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62991314/1701388. Possibly a duplicate?

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll try it out and update this issue.